# Using the turn gem with Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testunit

I'm using Turn gem in a rails app to colourise my Test::Unit output, and I find the following output before any of my tests run:

```
stephen@x5:~/code/ruby$ rake test
gem install minitest
gem install minitest
... tests seem to run just fine, and are nicely coloured
```

This happens everytime I run them. What is the deal here? Am I supposed to be using minitest instead of Test::Unit?

What is the best way to colourise Test::Unit output? Just looking for red and green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem 'redgreen'` worked great for me (on Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.7) with Test::Unit.

Add the above to your Gemfile.

On [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/redgreen).

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot earlier today, right before I decided to switch back to rspec! I'll try test::unit again, in another life, perhaps. A long time from now. :)

Comment: I actually switched to RSpec about 4 months ago...it seems to be more popular than Test::Unit.